# Prove that Autonomous are invariant under time translation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Reading my way through a big boy ODE book, and the authors write *It is clear that if $\varphi(t)$ is a solution to $x'=f(x) \quad x(t_0)=x_0$, then clearly $\varphi(t+t_0)$ is a solution to $x'=f(x) \quad x(0)=x_0$*.

I want to prove that, but am having a hard time doing it.  I begin by saying that $z=t+t_0$ and show that $\varphi(z)$ also satisfies the ODE, but I can't quite show the bit about the IC.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $\varphi(z = 0) = \varphi(t_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

That $\varphi$ solves the first one implies that $\varphi(t_0)=x_0$. If $x(t)=\varphi(t+t_0)$, just note that $x(0)=\varphi(t_0)=x_0$.